# pyqt5 QPushButtone hover style when it's flat=True

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a hover style of a QPushButton When it is flat, is it possible?. Seems hover is not showing with flat. If not, how can I make a similar flat style with a QPushButton with hover.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        
        self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self, flat=True)
        self.button.setStyleSheet(""" QPushButton {
                                                                background-color: yellow;
                                                                }
                                                                
                                                                QPushButton#pushButton:hover {
                                                                    background-color: blue;
                                                                }
                                                                
                                                                QPushButton#pushButton:pressed {
                                                                    background-color: orange;     
                                                                }"""
                                                            )
        self.button.move(100,70)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, your code would not work properly anyway, because you didn't set the objectName for the button. Then, have you tried to set the border property also? Remember that there is the `:flat` pseudo state too (but the border will probably will be necessary anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example how to make flat button with hover

```
self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button',self)
self.button.setStyleSheet(open('style.css').read())
```

And style.css

```
QPushButton {
    padding: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: orange;     
}
```

Link to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) to read more options.